# Increment version in a text file

Tags: powershell, versioning

I have a text file that contains only one line with a version number of my application. An example would be 1.0.0.1. I would like to increment the build number. Using my example I would get the output 1.0.0.2 in the same text file.

How can I do it with PowerShell?

Comment: This can be done but text files themselves do not have version numbers. Do you mean the name of the file or its contents?

Comment: Sorry for that, I meant it's contents..

Comment: So the only contents of the file is that text then?

Comment: Yes, the content is just 4 numbers divided by dots just like I stated above i.e: 1.0.0.1

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This might be over kill, but it shows the use of the type `[version]` which will save the need to do string manipulation.

```powershell
$file = "C:\temp\File.txt"
$fileVersion = [version](Get-Content $file | Select -First 1)
$newVersion = "{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}" -f $fileVersion.Major, $fileVersion.Minor, $fileVersion.Build, ($fileVersion.Revision + 1)
$newVersion | Set-Content $file
```

The file contents after this would contain `1.0.0.2`. The unfortunate part about using `[version]` is that the properties are read-only, so you can't edit the numbers in place. We use the format operator to rebuild the version while incrementing the `Revision` by one.

On the off chance there is some whitespace or other hidden lines in the file we ensure we get the first line only with `Select -First 1`.

One of several string manipulation based solution would be to split the contents into an array and then rebuild it after changes are made.

```powershell
$file = "C:\temp\File.txt"
$fileVersion = (Get-Content $file | Select -First 1).Split(".")
$fileVersion[3] = [int]$fileVersion[3] + 1
$fileVersion -join "." | Set-Content $file
```

Split the line on its periods. Then the last element (third) contains the number you want to increase. It is a string so we need to cast it as an `[int]` so we get an arithmetic operation instead of a string concatenation. We then rejoin with `-join`.

Comment: That did the trick perfectly, I understand all the commands except for Select -First 1. Does it mean take the first raw?

Comment: @mfuxi `Select-Object -First $x` return the first `$x` items and throws the rest away

Answer (score 3):

```
$versionFile = Get-Content -Path "c:\temp\testing.txt"
$version = [version]($versionFile)

$newVersion = New-Object -TypeName System.Version -ArgumentList $version.Major, $version.Minor, $version.Build, ($version.Revision + 1)
$newVersion | Set-Content -Path "c:\temp\testing.txt"
```

Comment: @Matt your solution also looks great but indeed, the `New-Object` avoids having to parse your own version number. Would be nice if `System.Version` had  `NextRevision()`, `NextBuild()`,... methods that returned a new Version

Comment: When I saw this question I thought it would be a great use for `[version]` until I got the read-only errors.

Answer (score 0):

One more string variation that removes the redundant assignment to the array member and includes a reminder on how to address the last element of an array. I think it is a little cleaner.

```
$file="C:\scripts\assemblyVersion.txt"
$versionparts = (get-content -Path $file).split('.')
([int]$versionparts[-1])++
$versionparts -join('.') | set-content $file
```