# Get and Replace AssemblyVersion from AssemblyInfo.cs

Tags: powershell

I have a regex I'm using (in test only) to update the `AssemblyVersion` from the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file. I'm wondering, however, what the best way to pull and replace this value from the `.cs` file itself would be?

Here is my best guess which, obviously, isn't working but the general idea is in place. Was hoping for something a little more elegant.

```
Get-Content $file | Foreach-Object{
    $var = $_
    if($var -contains "AssemblyVersion"){
        $temp = [regex]::match($s, '"([^"]+)"').Groups[1].Value.Substring(0, $prog.LastIndexOf(".")+1) + 1234
        $var = $var.SubString(0, $var.FirstIndexOf('"') + $temp + $var.SubString($var.LastIndexOf('"'), $var.Length-1))
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Per request here is the line I'm looking to update in the AssemblyInfo:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Comment: Added the `AssemblyVersion` line to the post

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Not really intending to change your regex but wanting to show you the flow of what you could be trying.

```
$path = "C:\temp\test.txt"
$pattern = '\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\("(.*)"\)\]'
(Get-Content $path) | ForEach-Object{
    if($_ -match $pattern){
        # We have found the matching line
        # Edit the version number and put back.
        $fileVersion = [version]$matches[1]
        $newVersion = "{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}" -f $fileVersion.Major, $fileVersion.Minor, $fileVersion.Build, ($fileVersion.Revision + 1)
        '[assembly: AssemblyVersion("{0}")]' -f $newVersion
    } else {
        # Output line as is
        $_
    }
} | Set-Content $path
```

Run for every line and check to see if the matching line is there. When a match is found the version is stored as a `[version]` type. Using that we update the version as needed. Then output the updated line. Non-matching lines are just outputted as is.

The file is read in and since it is in brackets the handle is closed before the pipeline starts to process. This lets us write back to the same file. Each pass in the loop outputs a line which is then sent to `set-content` to write back to the file.

---

Note that `$var -contains "AssemblyVersion"` would not have worked as you expected as `-contains` is an array operator. `-match` would be preferable as long as you know that it is a regex supporting operator so be careful for meta-characters. `-like "*AssemblyVersion*"` would also work and supports simple wildcards.

Comment: Wow, this is perfect. I was not aware powershell specifically had access to Major/Minor etc file versions. Thanks!!!

Comment: @NealR This comes partly from another answer of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30195025/increment-version-in-a-text-file/30195294#30195294. Only set back is the type has read only properties.

Comment: Great answer, thank you.  I made a few modifications which address a few issues I ran into - [gist](https://gist.github.com/blakeja/5655fe2ac52ff26fdec9ffa481c18dd9). Specifically, adding start/end anchors to the regex, handle versions which use the * character, read/write the file with UTF-8 encoding explicitly specified.