# Updating assembly info using powershell

Tags: powershell, teamcity

I want to update all assemblyinfo.cs in teamcity checkout directory. Referred this post [Get and Replace AssemblyVersion from AssemblyInfo.cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200323/get-and-replace-assemblyversion-from-assemblyinfo-cs). Looks like some logic is missing and file is not getting updated. 
It should update line 
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.4.0.0")] to
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.4.0.%build.counter%")]

```
$BuildCounter = "%build.counter%"
$pattern = '\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\("(.*)"\)\]'enter code here
Get-ChildItem -r -filter AssemblyInfo.cs | foreach-object { $name = $_.FullName}
{

(get-content $name ) | ForEach-Object{
    if($_ -match $pattern){
        # We have found the matching line
        # Edit the version number and put back.
        $fileVersion = [version]$matches[1]
        $newVersion = "{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}" -f $fileVersion.Major, $fileVersion.Minor, $fileVersion.Build, $BuildCounter 
        '[assembly: AssemblyVersion("{0}")]' -f $newVersion
    } else {
        # Output line as is
        $_
    }
} | Set-Content $name

}`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 7):

Never Mind, Just got it working, Looks like syntax problem

```
$BuildCounter = "build.counter"
$pattern = '\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\("(.*)"\)\]'
$AssemblyFiles = Get-ChildItem . AssemblyInfo.cs -rec


foreach ($file in $AssemblyFiles)

{

(Get-Content $file.PSPath) | ForEach-Object{
    if($_ -match $pattern){
        # We have found the matching line
        # Edit the version number and put back.
        $fileVersion = [version]$matches[1]
        $newVersion = "{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}" -f $fileVersion.Major, $fileVersion.Minor, $fileVersion.Build, $BuildCounter 
        '[assembly: AssemblyVersion("{0}")]' -f $newVersion
    } else {
        # Output line as is
        $_
    }
} | Set-Content $file.PSPath

}
Write-Host "##teamcity[buildNumber '$newVersion']"
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need such script at all, TeamCity has this feature built-in. It is called **AssemblyInfo Patcher**.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/assemblyinfo-patcher.html