# How do I pass assembly version from build step to next step

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a simple windows application in my Azure DevOps repo. I'm trying to set a build for it so I can practice using the Azure Pipelines.

How would I pass the assembly version of the c# windows application which resides in the AssemblyInfo.cs file under the project properties to use in a next step of the pipeline?

Comment: Why do you need to pass the assembly version on to the next step of the pipeline? I suspect this is an XY Problem, but more context should clear it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First you need get assembly version. You can use powershell script to read that value from file. This post may help you with [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200323/get-and-replace-assemblyversion-from-assemblyinfo-cs)
2. You need set variable to keep you assembly version. It also can be done in powershell script. You can read about this [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md)

   Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=AssemblyVersion;]$assemblyVersionFromFile"