# converting pom.xml version to number format

Tags: powershell

I have a requirement to increment to read and increment the pom.xml version by 1 using powershell script.

I was able to fetch the version value as for example: 1.0.123, but the type given here is string, when I try to convert it into Decimal or Double I am getting below error:

**Code:**

```
PS C:\Users\XXXX\Downloads> $finale
1.0.153

PS C:\Users\XXXX\Downloads> $finale.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                      
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                      
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

**Error:**

```
PS C:\Users\XXXX\Downloads> $finale1 = [Double]::Parse($finale)
```

> Exception calling "Parse" with "1" argument(s): "Input string was not in a correct format."
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + $finale1 = [Double]::Parse($finale)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException

Comment: Why do you want it to convert to a Double? Just parse it to a version: `[Version]::Parse("1.0.123")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increment version in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30195025/increment-version-in-a-text-file)

Comment: You could split the string in three different integers and increment the one you need before recreating your string.

Comment: @guiwhatsthat I wanted to increment the number, which is why I was searching for conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `[version]` type is nice, but it is immutable. This code splits it into an array, increments the third (Build) number, and produces a string in $newfinale.

Note that this does not check to see if there is a third (Build) value. It will produce an exception if the $finale is '1.2'.

```
PS C:\> $finale = '2.3.4.5'
PS C:\> $a = $finale.split('.')
PS C:\> $a[2] = [int]$a[2] + 1
PS C:\> $newfinale = $a -join '.'
PS C:\> $newfinale
2.3.5.5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,  I have used this and my script is working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is 1.0.123 is not math. It is nether an integer, nor a double. It is simply a string that contains numbers and symbols. This is why you are getting the error.

See the following Help files:
[About_Arithmetic_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators?view=powershell-6)
[.NET Math Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math?view=netframework-4.7.2)