# Powershell: how to split, do math and format

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a 1-liner that looks something like this:

```bsh
(gitversion | ConvertFrom-Json).SemVer.split('.') | [string]::Format("{0}.{1}.{2}",$_[0],$_[1] + 1,$_[2]) | git tag $_
```

So, right now I have `0.1.0` and I want a 1 liner that will map it to:
`0.2.0`

I am sure a guru in PS can make fast work of this

Comment: Powershell actually knows what version numbers are ... `'0.2.0' -as [VERSION]`. This way you can correctly calculate with version numbers or compare them properly ...

Answer (score 4):

You can read in the entire json, use the Major, Minor and Patch number of the version and update whichever one you are interested in... patch, minor or major.

I am using `foreach-object` to access all the properties of the json even though there is only one available. **1-liner**:

```
gitversion | ConvertFrom-Json | % { "$($_.Major).$($_.Minor + 1).$($_.Patch)" } | % { git tag $_ }
```

---

> **How can % / ForEach-Object work with multiple repositories**

If there is only one repository at the path you are running gitversion, it will always give you one object. *(gitversion fails with errors when you run this in directory that doesnt have a git repository.)*

I would like to stress that this would work great in your scenario where there is only Major, Minor and Patch version. In cases where the SemVersion is like, `"SemVer":"0.1.0"`, this is fine. But, if your interest is to keep the PreReleaseTag as well in your next version (and not drop the alpha / beta etc tags), you can include the PreReleaseTagWithDash to your output as well. e.g of pre-release tags: `"SemVer":"0.1.0-alpha.915"`

```
gitversion | ConvertFrom-Json | % { "$($_.Major).$($_.Minor + 1).$($_.Patch)$($_.PreReleaseTagWithDash)" } | % { git tag $_ }
```

**Sample JSONs of gitversion**

- From dev or other branches, you can expect variations in semVer that includes pre-release tags.

```
{
  "Major":0,
  "Minor":1,
  "Patch":0,
  "PreReleaseTag":"alpha.915",
  "PreReleaseTagWithDash":"-alpha.915",
  "PreReleaseLabel":"alpha",
  "PreReleaseNumber":915,
  "WeightedPreReleaseNumber":915,
  "BuildMetaData":"",
  "BuildMetaDataPadded":"",
  "FullBuildMetaData":"Branch.dev.Sha.888xxx.xxx888",
  "MajorMinorPatch":"0.1.0",
  "SemVer":"0.1.0-alpha.915",
  "LegacySemVer":"0.1.0-alpha915",
  "LegacySemVerPadded":"0.1.0-alpha0915",
  "AssemblySemVer":"0.1.0.0",
  "AssemblySemFileVer":"0.1.0.0",
  "FullSemVer":"0.1.0-alpha.915",
  "InformationalVersion":"0.1.0-alpha.915+Branch.dev.Sha.888xx.xx888",
  "BranchName":"dev",
  "Sha":"888xx.xx888",
  "ShortSha":"7a1152f",
  "NuGetVersionV2":"0.1.0-alpha0915",
  "NuGetVersion":"0.1.0-alpha0915",
  "NuGetPreReleaseTagV2":"alpha0915",
  "NuGetPreReleaseTag":"alpha0915",
  "VersionSourceSha":"88xxx.xx88",
  "CommitsSinceVersionSource":915,
  "CommitsSinceVersionSourcePadded":"0915",
  "CommitDate":"2019-12-06"
}
```

- From master branch, you would normally expect a semver = major.minor.patch.

```
{
  "Major":0,
  "Minor":1,
  "Patch":0,
  "PreReleaseTag":"",
  "PreReleaseTagWithDash":"",
  "PreReleaseLabel":"",
  "PreReleaseNumber":"",
  "WeightedPreReleaseNumber":"",
  "BuildMetaData":0,
  "BuildMetaDataPadded":"0000",
  "FullBuildMetaData":"0.Branch.master.Sha.9999xxx....xxx999",
  "MajorMinorPatch":"0.1.0",
  "SemVer":"0.1.0",
  "LegacySemVer":"0.1.0",
  "LegacySemVerPadded":"0.1.0",
  "AssemblySemVer":"0.1.0.0",
  "AssemblySemFileVer":"0.1.0.0",
  "FullSemVer":"0.1.0+0",
  "InformationalVersion":"0.1.0+0.Branch.master.Sha.999xxx...xxx999",
  "BranchName":"master",
  "Sha":"86b0be929a84ba7e9b2a463e7dbdc9a3c9325dc1",
  "ShortSha":"86b0be9",
  "NuGetVersionV2":"0.1.0",
  "NuGetVersion":"0.1.0",
  "NuGetPreReleaseTagV2":"",
  "NuGetPreReleaseTag":"",
  "VersionSourceSha":"999xxx...xxx999",
  "CommitsSinceVersionSource":0,
  "CommitsSinceVersionSourcePadded":"0000",
  "CommitDate":"2018-02-18"
}
```

**NOTE**: I have not tested this with multiple git repositories in one location. This solution will work if there is only repository at the path you are running.

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for - by splitting it I actually made the problem harder. I am still way too used to `bash`

Answer (score 3):

Note: **The solutions below assume that a *string* representation such as `0.1.0` is to be parsed**; as it turns out, the JSON that [utility `gitversion`](https://gitversion.net/docs/usage/command-line) outputs has *individual version-number components* such as `Major`, `Minor`, ..., which [Jawad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60242835/45375) relies on; however, even utilizing the individual properties for synthesizing an output *string* can be challenging, if *all* semver version components are to be preserved.

---

For a solution that is both robust and convenient, use the **`[semver]`** ([`System.Management.Automation.SemanticVersion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-TR/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.SemanticVersion)) type that **PowerShell [Core] 6+** offers (command is spread across multiple lines for readability):

You can simply ***cast* a version string such as `0.1.0` to `[semver]`**, yielding an *object* with *numeric* `.Major`, `.Minor`, and `.Patch` properties, alongside others; you can construct a *new* `[semver]` instance from it, with the modified minor version and all other properties passed through:

```
(gitversion | ConvertFrom-Json).FullSemVer | foreach { 
   $v = [semver] $_;
   [semver]::new($v.Major, ($v.Minor+1), $v.Patch, $v.PreReleaseLabel, $v.BuildLabel) 
  } | foreach { 
        git tag $_ 
      }
```

<sup>`foreach` is the built-in alias for the  [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) cmdlet.

What the first `foreach` command outputs is a `[semver]` *object*, not a string, but passing such an object implicitly *stringifies* it, which yields the desired representation.</sup>

**The above ensures that *all* components of a [semver](https://semver.org/)-compliant version string are preserved on output**, notably including the pre-release and build-metadata fields, if present (e.g.,
`1.0.0-alpha+001`).

---

If your **version-number strings** are always **composed of 2 - 4 *numeric-only* components** (e.g., `1.0`, `1.0.2`, `1.0.2.10`), you can use the **`[version]`** type ([`System.Version`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Version)) instead, which is **also available in *Windows PowerShell*** (PowerShell versions 5.1 and below):

```
'0.1.0.34' | foreach { 
    $v = [version] $_; $newMinor = $v.Minor + 1
    if ($v.Build -ne -1 -and $v.Revision -ne -1) { [version]::new($v.Major, $newMinor, $v.Build, $v.Revision) }
    elseif ($v.Build -ne -1) { [version]::new($v.Major, $newMinor, $v.Build) }
    else {[version]::new($v.Major, $newMinor) }
   } | foreach { 
        git tag $_ 
      }
```

Note the - unfortunate - need to use `[version]`'s various constructor overloads selectively, which is the consequence of a design asymmetry: non-specified version components (for the optional build and revision fields) default to placeholder `-1`, but passing these placeholders to the 4-component constructor is *not* supported.

---

Note: The **advantage of the above solutions is that you get proper *object* representations of the version numbers, which make programmatic processing easier** in general.

- However, it is baffling that neither `[semver]` nor `[version]`
  themselves offer *methods* for incrementing the version numbers they represent.

---

For **convenience function `Increment-Version`**, which supports incrementing a given target component of both `[semver]` and `[version]` instances, see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60651451/45375).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this right, you want to add 1 to the 2nd number.  I wish I could do $a.minor += 1, but the [version] type is read-only.

```
$a = '0.1.0'
$nums = $a.split('.')
'{0}.{1}.{2}' -f $nums[0], ([int]$nums[1] + 1), $nums[2]

0.2.0
```

Or

```
$a = '0.1.0'
$nums = $a -split '\.'
([int]$nums[1])++
$nums -join '.'

0.2.0
```

Or

```
$a = '0.1.0'
$nums = $a.split('.')
([int]$nums[1])++
'{0}.{1}.{2}' -f $nums

0.2.0
```

I was also trying the ps 6 version of -replace with the scriptblock, but it became challenging.

See also [Increment version in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30195025/increment-version-in-a-text-file)

Here's another one, but it needs powershell 6 for the -replace with a scriptblock.  I'm using regex with positive lookahead and positive lookbehind, so I'm only replacing the number and not the 2 dots on each side.  This would only work with 3 numbers, unless you wanted to increment 2 middle numbers by 1, lol.  It certainly qualifies as a one-liner.

```
'0.11.0' -replace '(?<=\.)\d+(?=\.)', { [int]"$_" + 1 }

0.12.0


'0.11.11.0' -replace '(?<=\.)\d+(?=\.)', { [int]"$_" + 1 }

0.12.12.0
```