# Powershell Increment value by 0.0.1

Tags: json, powershell, version

I have a variables, which returns values from json:

```
$version = (Get-Content 'package.json' | ConvertFrom-Json).version
```

This value always goes in x.x.x format. It can be either 0.0.3 or 1.123.23 value.

My question is - how to increase the only patch value? E.g. I need to have 0.0.4 or 1.123.24 output values after transform.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert to a `[version]` object:

```
# read existing version
$version = [version](Get-Content 'package.json' | ConvertFrom-Json).version

# create new version based on previous with Build+1
$bumpedVersion = [version]::new($version.Major, $version.Minor, $Version.Build + 1)
```

Alternatively, split the string manually:

```
$major,$minor,$build = $version.Split('.')

# increment build number
$build = 1 + $build

# stitch back together
$bumpedVersion = $major,$minor,$build -join '.'
```

Comment: Well, your method is awesome, but for the first case I need to have a string - how I can achieve this? Out-String doesn't help http://prntscr.com/recmwd

Comment: @VasiliyVegas `"$bumpedVersion"` or `$bumpedVersion -as [string]` or `$bumpedVersion.ToString()` will all do :)

Answer (score 2):

To complement [Mathias' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60622883/45375) with a concise alternative based on the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375):

```
# PowerShell [Core] only (v6.2+) - see bottom for Windows PowerShell solution.
PS> '0.0.3', '1.123.3' -replace '(?<=\.)[^.]+$', { 1 + $_.Value }
0.0.4
1.123.4
```

- [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) `(?<=\.)[^.]+$` matches the last component of the version number (without including the preceding `.` in the match).
- [Script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) `{ 1 + $_.Value }` replaces that component with its value incremented by 1.

For solutions to incrementing *any* of the version-number components, including proper handling of `[semver]` version numbers, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60244123/45375).

---

In *Windows PowerShell*, where the script-block-based `-replace` syntax isn't supported, the solution is more cumbersome, because it requires direct use of the .NET [`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex) type:

```
PS> '0.0.3', '1.123.3' | foreach { 
       [regex]::Replace($_, '(?<=\.)[^.]+$', { param($m) 1 + $m.Value })
    }
0.0.4
1.123.4
```

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
C:\> $v = "1.2.3"
C:\> $(($v -split "\.")[0..1] + "$([int](($v -split '\.') |Select-Object -Index 2) +1)") -join "."
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$build = [int]($version.split(".")[2])+1
$bumpedversion = $version.split(".")[0], $version.split(".")[1], $build -join "."
```